# How to Overlay a Scrollable Sliver on a SliverAppBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, flutter-sliver, flutter-sliverappbar

I have a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar` and some slivers. I want to overlay some graphics on the `SliverAppBar` and have them scroll with the rest of the list.

Here's the code I've been working with:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: SliverTest(),
    );
  }
}

class SliverTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<SliverTest> createState() => _SliverTestState();
}

class _SliverTestState extends State<SliverTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 350.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: const Center(child: Text('My Parallax Image!')),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: const Alignment(0.0, -2.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        child: const Center(child: Text('Red')),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.teal[100 * ((index % 8) + 1)],
                    child: Center(child: Text('Item #$index')),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this setup, I want the red circle (which is currently clipped) to be drawn on top of the yellow section of the `SliverAppBar` (Please note that the yellow section is just a simple placeholder for some actual images with parallax effect, and the use of a solid yellow color is merely for simplicity's sake). I've placed the red circle inside a sliver because I want it to scroll along with the rest of the list when the user interacts with the scrollable area.

Could anyone provide a simple example of how to achieve this in Flutter? I'm open to any other solutions that utilize slivers, as they provide huge convenience to the other parts of my real app. Otherwise, I'm aware that I may recreate it without utilizing the slivers. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10):

Here you have another sample without using Listener/ScrollNotifications, just playing with the sizes :).

Result:

[image]

Code:

```dart
class SliverTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<SliverTest> createState() => _SliverTestState();
}

class _SliverTestState extends State<SliverTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const circleSize = 50.0;
    const expandedHeight = 350.0;
    const headerColor = Colors.yellow;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: headerColor,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: expandedHeight - circleSize / 2,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Container(
                  color: headerColor,
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Yellow')),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                height: 200, //any size
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      top: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      height: circleSize / 2,
                      child: Container(
                        color: headerColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        width: circleSize,
                        height: circleSize,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        child: const Center(child: Text('Red')),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.teal[100 * ((index % 8) + 1)],
                    child: Center(child: Text('Item #$index')),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**

Ok, based on your latest comment, I had to go deeper :), now it's working as expected from your last requirements (but more complex too).

Results:

[image]

Code:

```dart
class SliverTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<SliverTest> createState() => _SliverTestState();
}

class _SliverTestState extends State<SliverTest> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final _layerLink = LayerLink();
  final _expandedHeight = 350.0;

  final _circleSize = 50.0;
  double _visiblePercent = 1.0;
  OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry;

  void _onListen() {
    final total = _scrollController.offset + kToolbarHeight + _circleSize / 2;
    final difference = total - _expandedHeight;
    _visiblePercent =
        ((_circleSize - difference).clamp(0.0, _circleSize).toDouble() /
            _circleSize);
    _overlayEntry?.markNeedsBuild();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(_onListen);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _showCircularItem();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(_onListen);
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _overlayEntry?.remove();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _showCircularItem() {
    _overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: CompositedTransformFollower(
            link: _layerLink,
            offset: Offset(0.0, -_circleSize / 2),
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: ClipRect(
                clipper: _MyClipper(
                  visiblePercent: _visiblePercent,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: _circleSize,
                  height: _circleSize,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Red')),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry!);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: _expandedHeight,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Image.network(
                  'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/49/86/39/360_F_549863991_6yPKI08MG7JiZX83tMHlhDtd6XLFAMce.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: CompositedTransformTarget(
                link: _layerLink,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                  height: 200, //any size
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.teal[100 * ((index % 8) + 1)],
                    child: Center(child: Text('Item #$index')),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  _MyClipper({
    required this.visiblePercent,
  });

  final double visiblePercent;

  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return Rect.fromLTRB(
      0.0,
      size.height * (1.0 - visiblePercent),
      size.width,
      size.height,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(_MyClipper oldClipper) {
    return visiblePercent != oldClipper.visiblePercent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your creative solution. It’s a clever visual trick using the matching yellow colors to create the illusion of layering, it's fine for solid colors. _However_, in my case, the yellow **placeholder** will be replaced with actual images. _The use of a solid yellow color was merely for simplicity’s sake_. Therefore, it does not work in my case. Could you please suggest a solution that would work with images instead of solid colors?

Comment: sure, I didn't know that , now I updated my answer :). Enjoy!

Comment: It seems quite promising. I'm looking forward to trying it out. Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you for all your efforts.

Comment: @goodUser was this answer helpful? If so you can mark this as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a [`Stack` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) to overlay the graphic on top of the `SliverAppBar`. The challenge is, however, to make the graphic scroll along with the `CustomScrollView`. You can try and adjust the position of the graphic in response to the scroll offset of the `CustomScrollView`.

Use a [`NotificationListener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html) to listen to scroll events. Calculate the position of the graphic based on the scroll offset. Use a `Stack`and adjust the position of the graphic dynamically as the user scrolls.

```dart
class _SliverTestState extends State<SliverTest> {
  double _offset = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
          onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
            setState(() {
              _offset = scrollInfo.metrics.pixels;
            });
            return true;
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverAppBar(
                    expandedHeight: 350.0,
                    floating: false,
                    pinned: true,
                    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      background: Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        child: const Center(child: Text('Yellow')),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // other slivers
                ],
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 350 - _offset, // Adjust position based on scroll offset
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 25,
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Red')),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can see the `NotificationListener` listening to scroll events and updating the `_offset` variable. The `Stack` widget overlays the red circle over the `CustomScrollView`. And the `Positioned` widget adjusts the position of the red circle based on the scroll offset.

See if that would place the red circle on top of the `SliverAppBar` and make it scroll with the rest of the list.

---

> There are some caveats.
>
> For example, since the graphics (the Red circle) is not actually part of any sliver, it obviously does not take part in the over-scroll effect, keeping its fixed position, thus exhibiting some design shortcomings, hence my emphasis in the OP.
>
> Also, after examining it, I realized that the Red circle needs to get behind the very `SliverAppBar`, that I insisted on being overlaid upon. Is there an easy fix for that?

To address the requirements of having the red circle scroll along with the slivers and also appear behind the `SliverAppBar`, you can try and use a [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) with a [`SliverPersistentHeader`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeader-class.html). The `SliverPersistentHeader` will allow you to create a custom header that behaves like a `SliverAppBar` but with more control over its contents and layout.

So, create a `SliverPersistentHeader` that includes the yellow background and the red circle. Adjust the position of the red circle within the custom header so that it initially appears in the desired location but still scrolls with the rest of the content. By using a `SliverPersistentHeader`, the red circle should naturally be placed behind the `SliverAppBar` as it scrolls.

```dart
class _SliverTestState extends State<SliverTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 350.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text('App Bar'),
              ),
            ),
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: _CustomHeaderDelegate(
                minHeight: 100.0,
                maxHeight: 350.0,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Red')),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // other slivers
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CustomHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;
  final Widget child;

  _CustomHeaderDelegate({
    required this.minHeight,
    required this.maxHeight,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => maxHeight;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_CustomHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}
```

The `SliverAppBar` should remain pinned at the top, and the custom header scrolls up underneath it.
Check if you see the red circle scroll with the rest of the list and stay behind the `SliverAppBar`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The scroll listener idea does indeed reflect the requirements of the original post, and I appreciate it. However, there are some caveats. For example, since the graphics (the Red circle) is not actually part of any sliver, it obviously doesn’t take part in the over-scroll effect, keeping its fixed position, thus exhibiting some design shortcomings, hence my emphasis in the OP. Also, after examining it, I came to a realization that the Red circle needs to get behind the very SliverAppBar, that I insisted to be overlaid upon. Is there an easy fix for that?

Comment: @goodUser Good points. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts in trying to answer my question. I appreciate the time and thought you've put into this. However, your latest update seems to have deviated from the direction I was hoping for. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77592509/14063881), while not completely correct, is more aligned with the solution I'm seeking. I kindly encourage you to please revisit their approach as it might give you a clearer idea of what I'm looking for. Thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: @goodUser I see. diegoveloper's answer, with their `CompositedTransformTarget` and `CompositedTransformFollower` should be a better fit indeed.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution for your problem based on what I understood.

```
class SliverTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<SliverTest> createState() => _SliverTestState();
}

class _SliverTestState extends State<SliverTest> {
  late ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar.large(
              pinned: true,
              floating: false,
              stretch: true,
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              expandedHeight: 350.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
              title: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Red')),
                ),
              ),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Yellow')),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                // height: 100,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) ...[
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              color: Colors.teal[100 * ((i % 8) + 1)],
                              child: Center(child: Text('Item #$i')),
                            )
                          ],
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // SliverList(
            //   delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            //     (BuildContext context, int index) {
            //       return Container(
            //         height: 50,
            //         color: Colors.teal[100 * ((index % 8) + 1)],
            //         child: Center(child: Text('Item #$index')),
            //       );
            //     },
            //     childCount: 20,
            //   ),
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but no, that's not what I'm looking for. You can examine the code in my original post, or check the other answers to get the whole picture that I'm after.

Answer (score -1):

**To make the circle unobstructed by the appBar:**
You can change **SliverAppBar** to **SliverPersistentHeader**. And customize your title and red circle in the **delegate** section, now the red circle will always be on top and not covered by the appBar anymore.

**How to customize the red circle according to the scroll of the list or the scroll of the appBar**:
If you want to scroll by list you just need to add ScrollController to the list. and listen for scrollController. If you want to change the scroll follow the appBar, then in the delegate section of the build function, there is an option shrinkOffset available so you can calculate this.

[Update 2023/12/08]

[source](https://github.com/BrianTV98/miracle_sliver_app_bar)

**Illustrations**

[image: Illustrations]

Comment: Thanks for your response. It would be really helpful if you could provide a code snippet demonstrating your suggestions.

Comment: @goodUser I went through a few other developers' answers and your responses to those answers. I feel like I still don't really understand your wishes. However, I will also write a small example, to talk about how I understand your wishes.

Comment: In my example there will be 4 components.
1 sliver app Bar (customize with SliverPersistentHeader,), 1 any widget (here is a blue circle), 1 list, 1 background image for sliver app bar.

The above 4 ingredients are completely independent and can be replaced with whatever you desire.

The Backgroup has a transparency that changes when scrolled. The blue circle also has content that changes when scrolled.

Comment: Although I don't really understand you, every effect and layer in my example is customizable, you can customize it according to your wishes.

I will edit the illustration on the answer and the entire source code on github. you can see at [link github](https://github.com/BrianTV98/miracle_sliver_app_bar)

Comment: Don't hesitate to share more, if my examples don't really meet your expectations